# React Proptypes - stateless components

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

```
<div className="dm-inbox-item__project">{props.message.project}</div>
```

I am trying to set out the propTypes within a stateless component, and wish to define propTypes for the properties on message.  Currently, I have only been successful in defining the whole message.

```
InboxItem.propTypes = {
  message: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};
```

I would like to do something like the below in order to validate individually.

```
Inbox.propTypes = {
  message.project: Proptypes.string.isRequired,
};
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that with `React.PropTypes.shape`.

```
Inbox.propTypes = {
    message: React.PropTypes.shape({
      project: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
    })
}
```